# invalid-or-expired-token-in-tweet-app using java Oauth2

Tags: java, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use the below code but for some reason I'm getting an invalid or expired token
Below the code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
ConfigurationBuilder cf= new ConfigurationBuilder();
cf.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("3Tt35OwMYXXXXXXIsLqVDf0Y")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("eMTbKXWvCgrc4k3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhJ1MWEtEFZnRZ")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("SonrEAXXXXXXXXXdD4UzcmBUuP4vsVmwZ4ZhHQF5")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("e1wR16ralA2ht0XXXXXXXXXXNhN5iv9izk1K1magOx");

    TwitterFactory tf =new TwitterFactory(cf.build());
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter= tf.getInstance();
    List<Status> status=twitter.getHomeTimeline();

    for(Status st:status){
        System.out.println(st.getUser().getName()+""+st.getText());
    }
}
```

and am getting below error when i run the class

```
 Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials   (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
message - Invalid or expired token.
code - 89
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at: http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=62590fa6 or http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=08f4a3c5
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[62590fa6-08f4a3c5], statusCode=401, message=Invalid or expired token., code=89, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1786)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getHomeTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:105)
at firsttwitapp.FirstTwitApp.main(FirstTwitApp.java:34)
```

C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 23 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same problem when I tried to make my TwitterBot. This problem is due to proxy issues of system, which is false by default. You can turn that on with this simple one line of code:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```